# Using `DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform()` inside a Swift actor

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I've a Swift actor that has a long-running update method that mutates a lot of shared state.
I want to perform the long-running work in parallel on a background queue, but avoid the update function becoming async due to the use of an TaskGroup. As using await inside the update function would make the actor re-entrant, which would allow other actor functions to run before the update is finished.

In the past I used `DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform()` to perform such CPU intensive computations on the background and this worked great.

However, when I apply this trick inside an actor in a Swift playground I get a compile time error (added as comment):

```
import Cocoa

actor Renderer {
    var items = [Int: Int]()

    func performUpdate() {
        var localItems = [Int: Int]()
        let lock = NSLock()

        DispatchQueue.global().sync {
            DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 10) { index in
                Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 10) //Some very CPU intensive computation
                Swift.print("Done: \(index)")

                lock.lock()
                localItems[index] = Int.random(in: 0...100) //Mutation of captured var 'localItems' in concurrently-executing code
                lock.unlock()
            }
        }

        items = localItems
    }
}

Task {
    let renderer = Renderer()
    await renderer.performUpdate()
    await Swift.print(renderer.items)
}
```

How can I 'export' the calculated results from inside the `concurrentPerform()` to the `performUpdate()` function?

And is using this construct even allowed under Swift's structured concurrency runtime contract? I think so, because the thread/task will always run to completion even though it might take a long while.

Is there a more Swiftly way of performing intensive calculations in parallel without making `performUpdate()` `async`?

Comment: Why do you not want to make `performUpdate` an `async` method? You are calling it from an asynchronous context and it is within an actor, so you `await` the result anyway. Why not make it `async`?

Comment: don't mix GCD and "Concurrency"  they are not compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the compile-time safety checks of the `actor` cannot reason about your use of locks to synchronize your access to `localItems`.

You can avoid these checks by moving this synchronization into a separate class and vouch for its safety with `@unchecked Sendable`:

```swift
actor Renderer {
    var items: [Int: Int] = [:]

    func performUpdate() {
        let localItems = SynchronizedDictionary<Int, Int>()

        DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 10) { index in
            let value = …                       //Some very CPU intensive computation
            localItems[index] = value
        }

        items = localItems.wrappedValue
    }
}

final class SynchronizedDictionary<Key: Hashable, Value>: @unchecked Sendable {
    private var values: [Key: Value] = [:]
    private let lock = NSLock()

    subscript(index: Key) -> Value? {
        get { lock.withLock { values[index] } }
        set { lock.withLock { values[index] = newValue } }
    }

    var wrappedValue: [Key: Value] {
        get { lock.withLock { values } }
        set { lock.withLock { values = newValue } }
    }
}
```

---

A few unrelated observations:

1. I have retired the `DispatchQueue.global().sync {…}`. The `sync` blocks the calling thread, so it offers no benefit. Yes, we use that pattern with `async` (and then give the function a completion handler) if we want to avoid blocking the calling thread, but if you are going to use `sync`, then it is redundant.
2. I know you said you wanted to avoid task groups and making this an `async` method, but should you ever reconsider that decision, it considerably simplifies our code. E.g.,

   ```swift
   actor Renderer {
       var items = [Int: Int]()

       func performUpdate() async {
           items = await withTaskGroup(of: (Int, Int).self) { group in
               for index in 0 ..< 10 {
                   group.addTask {
                       let value = …                  // computationally intensive
                       return (index, value)
                   }
               }

               return await group.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.0] = $1.1 }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Now, in this example with 10 iterations, the difference between this and the `concurrentPerform` example will be indistinguishable. And if you have so many iterations that the difference becomes observable, you might just have too many iterations. In those scenarios, even the `concurrentPerform` rendition would benefit greatly from “striding”. E.g., if I had 10m iterations, I might stride and then do 100 iterations, each handling 100k data points.

   FWIW, here is a random [benchmark](https://github.com/robertmryan/AsyncAwaitBenchmarks/tree/main) that I did with a computationally intensive task, comparing the performance of `concurrentPerform` and a task group. The difference was indistinguishable.

Comment: Thanks! I notice you also made Renderer a class, was that on purpose?
I certainly like the much simpler task group code (it's what I have now), but it requires al sorts of hacks to make sure there is no reentrancy during this update function. I think it's much cleaner to make this function non async than having all sorts of check code all over the place because this update functions performs a stupid (somewhat avoidable) `await`. I hope one day we get the `@reentrant(never)` attribute to decorate this function with.

Comment: Re `@reentrant(never)`, I’m hoping for that, or better, something that allows us to control the degree of reentrancy (not just 1 or *, but other values, e.g., 4 or 6), too. Sometimes we want constrained concurrency. E.g., sometimes for memory or server load reasons, we want to support some limited reentrancy.

Comment: Actually, turning on strict concurrency checking, and my prior solution was generating the same error. So I refactored this using legacy synchronization mechanism in a separate type. I hope that helps. @RemcoPoelstra